# What are __defineGetter__() and __defineSetter__() functions?

Tags: javascript

What are `__defineGetter__()` and `__defineSetter__()` functions in prototype of every `Object`?

Comment: [Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) :-)

Comment: It means 'old' and 'not currently in use'?

Comment: @DOtNET Ninja - "Old, no longer supported, and should not be used but are still there as to not break compatibility with people already using them".

Comment: Deprecated? Odd.. IE 11 just added support for it.

Comment: @SalmanPK - Meanwhile in 2014 `IE: Happy 2012 everyone!`

Comment: It's quite useful for KVO

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the [MDN docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters) for a description and example code:

> A getter is a method that gets the value of a specific property. A setter is a method that sets the value of a specific property. You can define getters and setters on any predefined core object or user-defined object that supports the addition of new properties.

As noted in the docs (and by @ cwallenpoole), `__define[GS]etter__()` functions are now deprecated. There's a lot more detail in [this article](http://whereswalden.com/2010/04/16/more-spidermonkey-changes-ancient-esoteric-very-rarely-used-syntax-for-creating-getters-and-setters-is-being-removed/). I believe the [defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) function is now the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question `__defineGetter__()` and `__defineSetter__()` are the old/original way to create a getter and a setter for an object's property. They allow you use an object's property as a name/value pair while behind the scenes these name/value pairs are supported by functions.

For example, let's say you wanted to reference some random numbers in fixed ranges. You could express these as words with the maximum of the range and it would look like a property.

```
var random = {};
random.__defineGetter__('ten', function() { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*10); });
random.__defineGetter__('hundred', function() { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*100); });
```

Note that the while the above example answers the question you should not use this solution. Instead you should use the modern form of getters and setters since ES5:

```
var random = {
    get ten() { return Math.floor(Math.random()*10); },
    get hundred() { return Math.floor(Math.random()*100); }
};
```

Either of the above constructs would allow you to get a random number like this:

```
var myrand = random.ten;
// returns a result in the range 0 to 9
```

Comment: Can't i do the same thing with a function, then what is the specific use of getter and setter ?

Comment: Yes you can. My example wasn't great because it just shows the pure usage of getters and setters. Usually the getter and setter will be backed by a variable and/or more computational functionality. For example, if you had an object called Temperature you could have a property C and F that return the temperatures in C or F. These aren't really properties but are methods (getters) that convert between the base value held in the object. Or one of them could be a property and the other a getter that does the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

`.__defineGetter__` it means when you refer to object.[param1] a function is executed.
`.__defineSetter__` it means when you set object.[param1] a function is executed.
for example, like this:

```js
const person = {
  firstName: 'john',
  lastName: 'doe',
};

person.__defineGetter__('fullName', () => `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`);
person.__defineSetter__('fullName', v => {
  person.firstName = v.split(' ')[0];
  person.lastName = v.split(' ')[1];
});
```

or if you want `cls` to clear the console,

```js
this.__defineGetter__('cls', console.clear);
```