# How does a browser know that an element has changed without a setter method, but just by assignment with '='?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How is it possible, that the browser can refresh the input element (or any other element), when I assign the value without a setter method, but just by normal assignment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("element_id").value = 'value';
</script>
```

Is there a native event, or is this a Javascript event? I would expect something like:

```
function setAttribute(value) {
  model.value = ...
  fireEvent();
}
```

But I can also set the attribute only without setter.

So where is this "event" fired (hidden somewhere in the assignment with '=') so that the browser knows that a refresh is needed?

Greetings

Comment: read about `property` feature of some programming languages

Comment: Also, this question is better suited to programmers.SE.

Comment: Changes to the Document Object Model are reflected immediately in the rendered page. I'm not sure if the underlying mechanism uses polling, a listener, etc.  But yeah you just assign values and the browser picks it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS engine is free to detect this however it wants. It could be a simple if (dest instanceof DOMElement) { special handling } or it could be an extremely complex process. It's just a simple assignment in JS land. In implementation land, it can do anything it wants as long as the end effect is correct.

In other words, it just looks like a simple assignment. Behind the scenes, it is most certainly more.

Comment: Of course that is true. But this must work on all browsers, since this is a basic feature. So I hoped that it is not a question about language interpretation, but about runtime envioronment. So perhaps __defineSetter/Getter__ or Object.defineProperty is really used by the browsers. However it could also be the case that the '=' is really interprated differently and the event is a natively supported.

Comment: @user2338867 As performance critical and deeply ingrained functionality as this is, I would be shocked if it's not implemented in native code.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can have [custom getters and setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) for object properties:

```
var obj = {
  get prop () { alert("Getting prop!"); return 4; }
  set prop (newValue) { alert("Setting prop to " + newValue); }
}

obj.prop = obj.prop + 1;
```

So here, the last line triggers both alerts.

Comment: If you're unluckly enough to care about IE8 or below, you won't be able to use this (it's a syntax error in browsers that don't support it).

Comment: Ok, so the assignment with triggering an event is possible with simple javascript. It is not native, neither of the browser nor of the language. It is part of the javascript language that I can add this getter/setter methods. However, it seems it is deprecated:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825191/what-are-definegetter-and-definesetter-functions

Comment: @user2338867: Well, `__defineSetter__` is, but `Object.defineProperty` and the shorthand literal syntax are not.

Answer (score 0):

Like Corbin says, the actual JS/DOM implementation of the browser can do whatever it wants. Javascript is *text* that is interpreted (or compiled) into something that runs in a virtual machine. What the text *means*, and what effects it has when interpreted - is up to the interpreter.

It's late and silly-time, so to demonstrate, a *very lousy* "parser/interpreter" written *in* javascript... It only allows one kind of statement and has no syntax checking (or much of anything else). But who knows - it still might give a (very simplified) idea of what's going on when the browser interprets an actual script:

```
var myscript1 = "value = 3";
var myscript2 = "othervalue = 5";

var variables = {};

// Hey ho, let's run our two "scripts":
parser(myscript1);
parser(myscript2);

function parser(script)
{
   // Super-simple lexer:
   var tokens = script.split(" ");

   // Rudimentary error checking:
   if (tokens.length != 3 || tokens[1] != "=")
   {
      alert("syntax error!");
   }

   var variable = tokens[0];
   var value = parseInt(tokens[2], 10);

   // Execute our only allowed operation:
   setVariable(variable, value);
}

function setVariable(name, value)
{
   // Store our value (e.g. for later use in our script - if our interpreter
   // actually allowed doing anything except assigning values to variables:
   variables[name] = value;

   // ... and do something with it:
   alert(name + " was set to " + value + "!");
}
```

Our "language" doesn't have function calls or events, but our "interpreter" can do whatever it wants with the "scripts" given to it. As Corbin said, it looks like simple assignment, but behind the scenes (in the `setVariable` function), it is most certainly more (well, in this case, a bit more - triggering an alert).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jimmi. Of course I know that each script can be interpreted differently if the execution environment is different. However there is sometimes a specification available (which does not mean, that all implementations are correct according to the specification). Unfortunately I did not know where to find the answer anywhere. Therefore I hoped that there is some language native construct, which supports this officially. It seems that it is either __defineSetter__ or Object.defineProperty. But if the DOM updates are really handled with these methods I do not know.

Comment: They aren't - since the JS engine and DOM handling aren't written in Javascript, and defineSetter/defineProperty are Javascript concepts. Here are: [The specification for the Javascript language (latest completed version 5.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) and [The DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/). Neither defines how Javascript or DOM manipulation is implemented, only their required behaviour. Each browser vendor may do it differently.