# Setter and Getter error

Tags: javascript, object

```
function Point () {
    this.xPos = 0;
    this.yPos = 0;
}

Object.__defineGetter__.call(Point.prototype, "getPoint", function(){
    return "X: " + this.xPos + " Y: " + this.yPos;
});

Object.__defineSetter__.call(Point.prototype, "setPoint", function(point){
    var parts = point.toString().split(', ');
    parts[0] = this.xPos;
    parts[1] = this.yPos;
});

var newPoint = new Point();

newPoint.setPoint("44.5, 60.6");

console.log(newPoint.getPoint);
```

It returns me an error : newPoint.setPoint is not a function. Dont get it why can you help me ? Trying to handle the setter and getter.

Comment: Why aren't you doing just `Point.prototype.getPoint = function(){...` instead

Comment: These functions are outdated, anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825191/what-are-definegetter-and-definesetter-functions. Use `get` or `set`.

Comment: Is it same ? Sorry i`m newbie in javascript. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem you are having is that setters are called by using the assignment operator `=` on it.

```
newPoint.setPoint = "44.5, 60.6";
```

```js
function Point () {
    this.xPos = 0;
    this.yPos = 0;
}

Object.__defineGetter__.call(Point.prototype, "getPoint", function(){
    return "X: " + this.xPos + " Y: " + this.yPos;
});

Object.__defineSetter__.call(Point.prototype, "setPoint", function(point){
    var parts = point.toString().split(', ');
    // the assignment to this.xPos and this.yPos was the wrong way around
    this.xPos = parts[0];
    this.yPos = parts[1];
});

var newPoint = new Point();

// a setter is called by assigning a value to it
newPoint.setPoint = "44.5, 60.6";

console.log(newPoint.getPoint);
```

You could also use the standard api of `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties` that will be easier to follow for anyone else looking at the code.

```
Object.defineProperty(Point.prototype, "getPoint", {
  get: function(){
    return "X: " + this.xPos + " Y: " + this.yPos;
  },
  set: function() {
    // stuff
  }
});
```

or with ES6

```
class Point {
  constructor() {
     this.xPos = 0
     this.yPos = 0
  }
  get getPoint() {
      // stuff
  }
  set setPoint() {
     // stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i've read **defineGetter** and **defineSetter** aren't used much anymore. You could do something like this:

```
function Point() {
  this.xPos = 0;
  this.yPos = 0;
}

Object.defineProperties(Point, {
  xPos: {
    set: function(newValue) {
      this.xPos = newValue;
    },

    get: function() {
      return this.xPos;
    }
  },

  yPos: {
    set: function(newValue) {
      this.yPos = newValue;
    },

    get: function() {
      return this.yPos;
    }
  }
});

newPoint = new Point();
console.log(newPoint.xPos);
newPoint.xPos = 45;
console.log(newPoint.xPos);
```

You can read more about using `Object.defineProperties` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).